# Como puedo lograr que los resultados se ordenan de forma ascendente?

Tags: c

Al ejecutar el programa me permite agregar los valores pero he no me los organiza de manera ascendente. Tienen alguna idea de que parte escribi mal en el código o cual debo de reformular para que me organice el resultado como deseo?

```
int main(){

          int nota, registro[11];
          int alterno;

for (nota=0; nota<11; nota++) {
    printf("Inserte la nota: ");
    scanf("%d", &registro[nota]);
}

for (nota=0; nota<11; nota++) {

    for (int j=0; j<11; j++) {

        if(registro[j] > registro[j+1]){

            alterno=registro[j+1];
            registro[j]=alterno;
            registro[j+1]=registro[j];
        }

    }

    printf("\nLa nota es: %d", registro[nota]);

}
getch();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

miremos un segundo tu codigo:

```
alterno=registro[j+1];
registro[j]=alterno;
registro[j+1]=registro[j];
```

Y ahora pongamos un ejemplo...

j = 5
j+1 = 7

entonces hagamos lo que dice tu codigo:
alterno = 7
registro[j] = 7
registro[j+1] = 7

Pero claro!!! como primero pasaste el alterno a j, y luego trataste de pasar j a j+1, entonces copiaste el mismo!!!

dos opciones.. o invertis las ultimas dos lineas:

```
alterno=registro[j+1];
registro[j+1]=registro[j];
registro[j]=alterno;
```

o a alterno, le pasas j

```
alterno=registro[j];
registro[j]=registro[j+1];
registro[j+1]=alterno;
```

### nota

Porque haces un for de las 11 notas y en cada vuelta ordenas todo??? primero ordena, y despues mostra las notas...

```
for (nota=0; nota<11; nota++) {
    for (int j=0; j<11; j++) {
        if(registro[j] > registro[j+1]){
            alterno=registro[j+1];
            registro[j+1]=registro[j];
            registro[j]=alterno;
        }
    }
}
for (nota=0; nota<11; nota++) {
    printf("\nLa nota es: %d", registro[nota]);
}
```